# JQGrid Pagination event,getting error

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-pagination

Need help on JQGrid pagination.
Below is the piece of code,

ERR LINE : `var currentPage = $('#gridData').getGridParam('page');` 
ERR MSG  :`0x800a01b6` - microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method.

I Have checked the Jquery references also..Everything is fine. Dont know where it is going wrong :(

```
$("#gridData").jqGrid({
    data: selectedTblData.Table.Rows,
    datatype: "local",
    toppager: true,
    height: "100%",
    width: (selectedTblData.Table.Width < 1000) ? 985 : "100%",
    altRows: true,
    altclass: "custom-alt-row",
    colNames: selectedTblData.Table.colNames,
    colModel: selectedTblData.Table.colModel,
    multiselect: false,
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [15, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    mtype: 'GET',
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: selectedTblData.Table.colNames[0],
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    shrinkToFit: (selectedTblData.Table.Width < 1000),
    caption: tableName,
    secureUri: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    loadonce: true,
    //BS Page start
    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        //debugger;


        var pagerId = this.p.pager.substr(1); // get paper id like "pager"
        var currentPage = $('#gridData').getGridParam('page'); //get current  page
        var lastPage = $("#gridData").getGridParam("lastpage"); //get last page 

        if (currentPage - 1 == lastPage - 1)
            $("#gridData").setGridParam({ page: lastPage }).trigger("reloadGrid"); // set the requested page to the last page value – then reload

        var currentRecordCount = $("#gridData").getGridParam("reccount");  //get the record count
        var recordsPerPage = $("#gridData").getGridParam("rowNum");  // get the records per page
        var newValue = 0;  // new value
        if (pgButton === "user") {
            newValue = $(".ui-pg-input").val(); 
        }
        else {

            if (pgButton.indexOf("next") >= 0)
                newValue = ++currentPage;
            else if (pgButton.indexOf("prev") >= 0)
                newValue = --currentPage;
            else if (pgButton.indexOf("last") >= 0)
                newValue = $("#gridId").getGridParam('lastpage');
            else if (pgButton.indexOf("first") >= 0)
                newValue = 1;
        }
        alert(newValue);
        $("#gridData").setGridParam({ page: newValue }).trigger("reloadGrid");  // set the requested page to the last page value – then reload
        currentRecordCount = $("#gridData").getGridParam("reccount");  // read the current page records
        alert('RecordCount: ' + currentRecordCount + ' RecordsPerPage: ' + recordsPerPage);

        if (currentRecordCount < recordsPerPage) {
            startRange = 1;
            endRange += endRange;

            jQuery("#gridData").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json", data: "{TableName :'" + tableName + "'}", url: "TablesCoolView.aspx/GetTableData" }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    }
    //BS page end
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is inconsistences with how you are calling the jqGrid methods. If I recall correctly, earlier versions of jqGrid used the

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGridMethod( parameter1,...parameterN );
```

way of calling methods, but I do believe the new API expect you to use th

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('method', parameter1,...parameterN );
```

so in your specific case, the way you are calling setGridParam on the last line is the best way

```
jQuery("#gridData").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json", data: ...
```

so you code that is like

```
$("#gridId").getGridParam('lastpage');
```

is not valid in the new API. (i.e. should be

```
jQuery("#gridData").jqGrid("getGridParam", 'lastpage');
```

Now this change was about version 3.6, so what version are you using as you seem to be mixing methods

ref [jqGrid methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

Although to be honest, I was reasonable positive that both methods were OK, but judging by your error message, the $('#gridData').getGridParam('page'); is throwing the error because $('#gridData') doesn't have a method getGridParam, so I would try the other way

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer....am using the following versions                                                               <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi,I have modified the code according to your suggestion.Everything is working fine.Only problem is reloading the Jqgrid,The following line is not firing                                                                jQuery("#gridData").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json", data: "{TableName :'" + tableName + "'}", url: "TablesCoolView.aspx/GetTableData" }).trigger("reloadGrid");                                            Please suggest some solution.Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly sure. Is the if statement evaluated to true> (i.e. if(currentRecordCount < recordsPerPage)), also is the path 100% correct (TablesCoolView.aspx/GetTableData) seems a bit strange to me. Shouldn't it be TablesCoolView.aspx?GetTableData=true or the likem don't usually see paths after the .aspx part of the file

Comment: Yes ,it is going to if statement.And for testing purpose i have added two alerts,one at the starting of the statement & another at the end of the statement.Both alerts are firing but this reload is not firing.and it is not going to serverside method also ,for debugging purpose.

Comment: So the other point, is the url correct? (TablesCoolView.aspx/GetTableData). You sure that it is not getting a 404 or 500 http error on request to that URL (you can check that under the developer tools, under the network tab on any major browser)

Comment: Aha - I think the main problem here is that you have the datatype set to local and (by the look of it) passing in rows from an HTML table, and you have manually written the paging functionality. Then you are expecting to change it to an ajax (JSON) grid with a URL. I would either make the whole grid an ajax (JSON) grid from the start (so you don't need to have the paging functionality) or keep it a local only grid and get the new data from a completely separate AJAX call that only returns an array (like you selectedTblData.Table.Rows) and then give that to the grid and reload

Comment: As I think loadonce: true is interfering with you ajax call